# Why tuple loads like constant in python in dis?

Tags: python

If we dis dict creation or list creation we can see that BUILD_ command is using:

```
>>> dis('{}')
1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
            2 RETURN_VALUE


>>> dis('[]')
1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
            2 RETURN_VALUE
```

But, if we dis tuple creation:

```
>>> dis('()')
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (())
            2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Is this related to the unchangeable nature of tuples?

Comment: Yes -- they're immutable, so you don't need to construct a new mutable object; you can just point directly at an instance the parser constructed when reading the literal.

Comment: Contrast with `dis('(1, [])')`

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this is a question based on "a problem you actually face". "Why" questions on language design are often off topic; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918

Comment: Maybe your right, but this question appeared when Im tried to optimize code to the maximum possible level, so I just dis all statements. So it was interested for me why tuple creation works differently from list and dict